# C# Desktop Application multi image select

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have this logic and I set dialog.Multiselect = true, so I can select multi images, but the problem is that I get only the first image path. Do you know how to get and the other images path, not only first

```
private void flatButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "Select Valid Document(*.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg)|*.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg";
            dialog.Multiselect = true;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                String path = dialog.FileName;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding()))
                {
                    textBox12.Text = path;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [FileDialog.FileNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) ? - [OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paths are in the `OpenFileDialog.FileNames` array.

Try this:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Select Valid Document(*.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg)|*.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg";
dialog.Multiselect = true;
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string fileName in dialog.FileNames)
    {
        // do something with path
    }
}
```